# Deploy salesforce objects from sandbox to developer account using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, migration

I am trying to move data from sandbox to developer account

```
i am getting below issues while moving objects

1. have a formula field in a csutom object, when i try to move the object.

 Error message on filtering items(formula field)

2. While in same process if a button is overrided by VF Page,then i am getting the issue as 

page does not exist.

If i try to move only custom fields with in the object getting issue as entity not found
```

Comment: Do you use ANT task for this purpose?

Can you show full error messages and show you package.xml ?

Comment: I am not using Ant i am using eclipse only

Comment: I mean do you use Eclipse Ant Panel? How do you put classes from sandbox to dev org?

Comment: are you using the Meta Data in "compare with" mode to ship your information across, or the force.com | Deploy wizard?